# change size of kendo window when pressing the "minimize" button

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to change the width of a kendoui window when the "minimize" button is pushed.  I'm new to kendo and coulnd't find the help in their docs.

Here's the code I've got:

HTML: `<div id="recon_cont_div">Some data here</div>`

```
var thewindow = $("#recon_cont_div");
thewindow.kendoWindow({
                          actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Pin", "Close"],
                          width: "100%",
                          height: "100%",
                          draggable: true,
                          resizable: true,
                          minimize: function(e) {
                                debugger;
                                thewindow.data("kendoWindow").setOptions({width: 250});
                          },
                          
                           close: function(e) {
                            alert("window will close now")
                          },
                          
                          title: "The window"
                    }).data("kendoWindow");
```

When the "minimize function" runs, the window does not resize...it does nothing?

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: try this  e.sender.setOptions({

  width: 250
});

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window wrapper is the one you need to change:

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  actions: ["Minimize"],
  minimize: function(e) {
    $("#dialog").getKendoWindow().wrapper.css({
        width: 200
    });
  }
});
```

Example: [Window size change](https://dojo.telerik.com/opOlAPOZ)